# Tabbing environment in tabular environment cancels set table width

Tags: tables, width, tabbing

I have a table with a tabbing environment in it. I don't want the table to exceed a certain width, but the tabbing environment seems to ignore this. So while inserting a lot of 'blas' in row 5 results in the blas being distributed over several lines (which is what I want), the blas in the tabbing environment in row 2 make the table wider (which I want to avoid).

How can I use a tabbing environment in a tabular environment while preserving the set width of my table?

Thanks in advance for any replies!

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|p{7cm}|}
 \hline
1 & xxx \\ \hline
2  & 


\begin{tabbing}
xxx:\hspace{6mm} \= \textbullet  \hspace{0.01mm} bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
\> \textbullet  \hspace{0.01mm} xxx\\
\> \textbullet  \hspace{0.01mm} xxx\\
xxx: \> \textbullet  \hspace{0.01mm} xxx\\
\> \textbullet  \hspace{0.01mm} xxx\\
xxx: \> \textbullet  \hspace{0.01mm} xxx\\
\> \textbullet  \hspace{0.01mm} xxx\\
xxx: \> \textbullet  \hspace{0.01mm} xxx\\
\> \textbullet  \hspace{0.01mm} xxx\\
\end{tabbing}

\\ \hline
3 & xxx \\ \hline
4 & xxx\\ \hline
5 & bla blabla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\\ \hline
6 & xxx\\ \hline
7 & xxx\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: tabbing cells are always one line, so what do you want to happen if the tabbing is wider than the specified 7cm ?

Comment: I would want the text to spread across multiple lines, but you make a good point: perhaps I should look for an alternative to the tabbing environment.

Comment: it looks  more like a list to me (list items wrap naturally in table cells)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `tabular` instead of `tabbing`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{\widthof{\textbullet}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|p{7cm}|}
 \hline
1 & xxx \\ \hline
2  &

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{1cm}p{\mylen}p{\dimexpr6cm-\mylen-5\tabcolsep\relax}}
xxx   & \textbullet  & bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
      & \textbullet  & xxx\\
      & \textbullet  & xxx\\
xxx:  & \textbullet  & xxx\\
      & \textbullet  & xxx\\
xxx:  & \textbullet  & xxx\\
      & \textbullet  & xxx\\
xxx:  & \textbullet  & xxx\\
      & \textbullet  & xxx\\
\end{tabular}
\\ \hline
3 & xxx \\ \hline
4 & xxx\\ \hline
5 & bla blabla blabla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\\ \hline
6 & xxx\\ \hline
7 & xxx\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{1cm}p{\mylen}p{\dimexpr6cm-\mylen-5\tabcolsep\relax}}` means

The tabular has three columns with first column 1cm, second one with `\mylen` and the third one with  `\dimexpr6cm-\mylen-5\tabcolsep\relax` wide respectively. `\mylen` is eaual to the width of `\textbullet` and  `\dimexpr6cm-\mylen-5\tabcolsep\relax` is `7cm -1cm-\mylen-5\tabcolsep` (the remaining available width for the third column). As there are three columns we have 6 `\tabcolsep`s of which the first one is made zero using `@{}`. `\tabcolsep` is the separation between column content and its border.

Hope it is clear.

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you! Could you briefly explain what this line says? :

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{1cm}p{\mylen}p{\dimexpr6cm-\mylen-5\tabcolsep\relax}}

Comment: @Thomas I have added some explanations. Hope it is useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! I'm still learning, so it's useful to try to understand the code rather than blindly copying and pasting it from the web.

Comment: OP should know that tabular environments cant be broken across pages. Its an issue im trying to solve now.

Comment: @dopatraman Use a `longtable` or `ltablex` (if you need text wide tables) ....